# Triggering a service call in one controller from another controller in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services, angular-controller

It is imperative I find a solution for it but I could not.

There are three states in my application. Search , Search Results and Search Details.

After I give  a transaction key for search in the Search Page,

[image]

the results are displayed on the search results page in a UI Grid and they have transaction status as "Waiting for approval".

[image]

Now When I click on the transaction key on the Search results page ..

I go the Search Details Page. That's a separate controller.

[image]

Now the approve button on the Search Details Page ...

should change the transaction status to "Approved" from "Waiting for approval" .

And it will be done via a StoredProcedure at the backend.

So all I have to do is

**I have to somehow update the search results page also to reflect the status Approved instead of Waiting for approval**.

But they are separate controllers in Angular.

How can I achieve this ?

**Update**

What I did till now , that did not work , is .........

When the approve button is clicked and the result is returned (that is , the transaction is approved now)

I am again firing the Transaction Search via $rootScope.$broadcast

```
        var searchResultsParam = TransactionDataServices.getSavedSearchParams();

        console.log("Search Results Params that are set  ...");
        console.log(searchResultsParam);

        //Fire the transaction search again 
        $rootScope.$broadcast('gridRefreshMergeResult', searchResultsParam);

        myApp.hidePleaseWait();

        $("#accessDeniedModal").modal('show');
```

and catching the same , at the SearchResult's controller .

```
$rootScope.$on('gridRefreshMergeResult', function (event, arg) {
    window.alert("Fired from merge");

    console.log("In Event Args after broadcast from Merge");
    console.log(arg);

    //Fire the search again
    TransactionServices.getTransactionAdvSearchResults(arg).then(function (result) {
        console.log("Trans Search Results");
        console.log(result);

        //Set the Grid UI data again
        $scope.searchResultsGridOptions.data = '';
        $scope.searchResultsGridOptions.data = result;
        TransactionDataServices.setSearchResultsData(result);
    });
});
```

but this thing is not working as expected ?

Sometimes the event is being fired and the alert is being shown more than once .

Any other alternative/more standard way of achieving the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's an approach. After clicking on Approve and getting the record approved, you can retrieve the record that was approved and then send a broadcast with the updated data. The broadcast is received by your search controller which then updates the record updated using its index.

```
//search results controller
$scope.editRecord = function(record){
    $scope.editRecordIndex = $scope.searchResults.indexOf(record);

    //Edit record state
    $state.go("editRecord");
}

$scope.$on("RECORD_UPDATED",function(source,args){
      $scope.searchResults[editRecordIndex] = args;
});




//record approval controller
$scope.approve = function(record) {
    TransactionDataService.approve(record).then(function(response){
        $rootScope.$broadcast("RECORD_UPDATED",response.record);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use $rootScope and events to do the same, make sure that you are only registering the event handler for gridRefreshMergeResult only once, there are two ways you could guarantee that, either by executing $rootScope.$on() code in the controller definition or app.run():

### using in controller definition:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, TransactionServices) {

// directly put your event handler registration here:
$rootScope.$on('gridRefreshMergeResult', function (event, arg) {
    window.alert("Fired from merge");

    console.log("In Event Args after broadcast from Merge");
    console.log(arg);

    //Fire the search again
    TransactionServices.getTransactionAdvSearchResults(arg).then(function (result) {
        console.log("Trans Search Results");
        console.log(result);

        //Set the Grid UI data again
        $scope.searchResultsGridOptions.data = '';
        $scope.searchResultsGridOptions.data = result;
        TransactionDataServices.setSearchResultsData(result);
    });
});

});
```

and you could fire it using the same way you wrote:

```
    var searchResultsParam = TransactionDataServices.getSavedSearchParams();

    console.log("Search Results Params that are set  ...");
    console.log(searchResultsParam);

    //Fire the transaction search again 
    $rootScope.$broadcast('gridRefreshMergeResult', searchResultsParam);

    myApp.hidePleaseWait();

    $("#accessDeniedModal").modal('show');
```

note that your controller must load at least once for the handler to be registered.

### Using app.run()

```
angular.module('myApp')
.run(function($rootScope, TransactionServices) {

$rootScope.$on('gridRefreshMergeResult', function (event, arg) {
    window.alert("Fired from merge");

    console.log("In Event Args after broadcast from Merge");
    console.log(arg.arg);

    //Fire the search again
    TransactionServices.getTransactionAdvSearchResults(arg.arg).then(function (result) {
        console.log("Trans Search Results");
        console.log(result);

        //Set the Grid UI data again
        args.scope.searchResultsGridOptions.data = '';
        args.scope.searchResultsGridOptions.data = result;
        TransactionDataServices.setSearchResultsData(result);
    });
});
});
});
```

using app.run(), you have to pass the $scope in the args:

```
    var searchResultsParam = TransactionDataServices.getSavedSearchParams();

    console.log("Search Results Params that are set  ...");
    console.log(searchResultsParam);

    //Fire the transaction search again 
    $rootScope.$broadcast('gridRefreshMergeResult',{arg: searchResultsParam, scope: $scope }); // you have to provide a reference to current $scope.

    myApp.hidePleaseWait();

    $("#accessDeniedModal").modal('show');
```